# Splitting data passed from a function

Tags: javascript

I have 2 functions:

```
function1() {
    let arraydata = ['data1', 'data2', 'data3'];
    function2(`save ${arraydata} thefilename`);
}

function2(data) {
    let theArray = data.content.split(" ")[1];
    let theFilename = data.content.split(" ")[2];
}
```

data on function 2 is retuning this:

```
save data1,data2,data3 thefilename
```

I need data on function2 to appear as:

```
save ['data1', 'data2', 'data3'] thefilename
```

so I can split it.

How can I do this?

Comment: You don't have complete functions. You are missing a `return`.

Comment: That's not how you pass an array around. Why would you encode it as a string, to only decode it from that string back into an array?

Comment: The code doesn't make sense, it's not valid JS. Please edit.

Comment: Basically I have this: 'save ['data1', 'data2', 'data3'] thefilename' and need to pass it as it is through a function parameter as a string...only 1 parameter is available

Comment: JSON.stringify + JSON.parse would do the trick

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not really sure what you're trying to do with this, but the easiest way would probably just be to change your first function to include the brackets:

```
function1() {
    let arraydata = ['data1', 'data2', 'data3'];
    function2(`save [${arraydata}] thefilename`);
}
```

This should pass the brackets in the string to your second function.

Comment: @KevinPorche oops, I just edited it because of the missing tick marks, my bad!  If the first solution worked, I can change it back.

Answer (score 0):

One solution would be:

```
function1() {
    let arraydata = ['data1', 'data2', 'data3'];
    function2(`save ['${arraydata.join("','")}'] thefilename`);
}

function2(data) {
    let theArray = data.content.split(" ")[1];
    let theFilename = data.content.split(" ")[2];
}
```

But this change from array to string representation and back to array will have
unexpected data conversion. For example, if `arraydata = [1, 2, 3]`, theArray would be `'['1', '2', '3']'`.

I don't know what is the goal of those functions, but maybe you could implement them like this:

```
function1() {
    let arraydata = ['data1', 'data2', 'data3'];
    function2('save', arraydata, thefilename);
}

function2(operation, data, filename) {
  /* Here goes your implementation */
}
```